# Unable to ping internet from switch

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ping, networking

Router internet interface Fastethernet0/0 192.168.0.17 (ip nat outside)

internal interface 192.168.1.1 (ip nat inside)

able to ping 8.8.8.8 from router

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            192.168.0.17    YES DHCP   up                    up
FastEthernet0/1            192.168.1.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up
NVI0                       unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
```

router config:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address dhcp
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly
no ip route-cache
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly
no ip route-cache
duplex auto
speed auto


ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

From switch able to ping both router intefaces but not 8.8.8.8

set default gateway on switch

```
ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Both are CISCO

switch config:

```
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
service password-encryption
!
hostname nemanja_SW1_35550
!
enable secret 5 $1$vc35$d7PthbPyFSMsiQlnQTMIU0
enable password 7 1218011A1B05
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone CST 1
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: are you able to ping 8.8.8.8 from the router (using F0/0 interface directly)?

Comment: Please include the switch config.

Comment: @Golgot, yes i can ping from F0/0

Comment: @RonTrunk-included

Comment: Please accept your own answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: @TeunVink accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution,had to change default route to

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

192.168.0.1 is ISP provider router

Answer (score -1):

I think you need an extended access list 
ip access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.25 any
change your nat statement to

ip nat inside source list 100 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload

Comment: @chuck-solved it was issue with default route